# Where does a creature summoned by planar ally appear?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

The spell [*planar ally*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-ally) has a range of 60ft and says:

> That entity sends a celestial, an elemental, or a fiend loyal to it to aid you, making the creature appear in an unoccupied space within range.

This implies to me that the spellcaster doesn't have any control over where specifically the creature appears other than that it needs to be within 60ft of him. Is that correct, or can the spellcaster choose where the creature appears?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## DM’s choice

The spell says a powerful NPC chooses where the creature appears in range. NPCs are controlled by the DM, so the DM will make the choice for the NPC and tell you where the summoned creature appears.